# Doubt regarding a problem in Ross book. Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $a \leq b_1$ for every $b_1>b$, then $a\leq b$

Tags: real-analysis

This question is from Kenneth A Ross book of Real Analysis. I have already solved the problem. My doubt is that statement does hold if we drop the condition that $a \leq b_1$ by $a<b_1$

Because result still holds. Proof goes like this. Assume on the contrary that $a >b$ then we can arrive at the contradiction by finding an element $c$ in between $a$ and $b$.

Am I wrong?

Comment: That's a weaker statement.  If $a < b_1$ for every $b_1$ then $a \le b_1$ for every $b_1$ and the proof follows.  But it's a weaker result.  This is a bit like saying: For every even $n$ then $X$ and deciding to replace "for every even $n$" with "for every $n$ divisible by $26$".  Its true because if $n$ is divisible by $26$ it is even but it's not as good a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're right: if $a >b$ find $c$ with $b < c < a$. By assumption $a < c$ as $c > b$. But we cannot have both $c<a$ and $a<c$, contradiction. So $a \le b$ as it does *not* hold that $a > b$.

So we can assume both $\forall b_1 >a: a \le b_1$ or $\forall b_1 >a: a < b_1$; the former is weaker so better (the same conclusion from a weaker assumption).

Comment: Is not the former stronger because it includes two condition $a<b_1$ or $a=b_1$. Maybe I am confused with term weaker and stronger. I would be thankful if you can say something on this.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician it's (slightly) easier to show the first condition because $a=b_1$ is also allowed. If the second is fulfilled so is the first, so the second is stronger. If $p$ implies $q$ then $p$ is stronger than $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that both conditions are equivalent, since

- $a \leq b  \Leftrightarrow \forall b_1 > b:\; a< b_1$ and
- $a \leq b  \Leftrightarrow \forall b_1 > b:\; a\leq b_1$

The second version turns out to be a bit more practical when working with inequalities, because you do not need to check wether the involved inequalities are "sharp".